# How can I insert blob in xml, using mysql?

Tags: mysql, xml, blob

I am using mysql and I'm trying to populate the database in build.xml.

How can I insert a blob file in this table:

```
        CREATE TABLE CONTENT (
        idContent varchar(30) not null,
        price int,
        url blob,
        primary key (idContent)
        );
```

I've tried this:

```
INSERT INTO CONTENT VALUES ("Tecnico.png", 0, LOAD_FILE("src/Tecnico.png"));
```

but the url return is null, then I tried the entire path to the .png and returned null to.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: "MySQL LOAD_FILE() reads the file and returns the file contents as a string. To use this function, the file must be located on the host server, user must specify the full path name of the file, and user must have the FILE privilege. The file must be readable and size must be less than max_allowed_packet (set in the my.ini file) bytes. It returns NULL if the file does not exist or can’t be read." Have you checked that the filename and path are correct?

Comment: Yes, multiple times. The .png file is in the same project that build.xml but inside the src folder. I'm working in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL LOAD_FILE() reads a file that is already present on the server, do not uploads the file.

So, if the file is on the server, and the full path is something like "/var/www/[AnotherFolfer]/src/Tecnico.png"

Try, to use:

```
INSERT INTO CONTENT VALUES ("Tecnico.png", 0, LOAD_FILE('/var/www/[AnotherFolder]/src/Tecnico.png'));
```

Comment: I think this could be the problem but launches another one. I'm doing this populate in a build.xml in an eclipse project. The file I want to   load is in the project/src folder. You are telling me I need to upload  the file first so I can load it into the table?